# Detecting initialisation change vs. user change in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

This feels like one of those questions that ought to be really obvious, but the answer is eluding me at the moment.

I have some XAML that resembles the following:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShouldCopySettings}"/>
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding CopySettingsFrom}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="ItemGroupStyle"/>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

The `ItemsSource` is to a `CollectionViewSource` further up that uses `GroupDescriptions`; I'm not sure if this is a factor or not.

Everything behaves as expected with respect to the underlying ViewModel objects with the basic implementation.  The initial state of the `ShouldCopySettings` property is false and the initial state of the `CopySettingsFrom` property is null.  The one unexpected (but tolerable) behaviour is that the combobox appears to auto-select the first item in the list when the parent DataContext is assigned, and fires the setter for the `CopySettingsFrom` property accordingly.

But now I would like to have it auto-tick the checkbox if the user makes a selection from the combobox.  My first inclination was to just assign true to the `ShouldCopySettings` property from the setter of the `CopySettingsFrom` property -- and indeed this does work.

However due to the initialisation issue mentioned above, when the DataContext is initially assigned (which occurs outside of this viewmodel's control) this will invariably result in ticking the checkbox and setting `ShouldCopySettings` to true regardless of its initial state in the data source, which is obviously unacceptable.

So I'm looking either for a way to detect that it's initialising the combo so that I can avoid changing the checkbox property, or for a better way to link these up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer to my own question because it does seem to work, but I'm not particularly happy with it and I welcome better alternatives.

What I've done for the moment is to modify the `CopySettingsFrom` setter so that it will only set the `ShouldCopySettings` property to true if the old value of its own property is a non-null value.

This makes it ignore the initial combobox init because that is a change from null to non-null.  Since it's not possible for user action to cause a change to null, this should never happen again.